# How to calculate transition areas of biomes in an image

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming, colorings

I'm generating biomes for my game and I would like to store them in a single RGB image like the one below. A color hue can then be mapped to an ID through a table lookup. The problem I face is that I would like the transition areas between the biomes to give an exact percentage of each biome's representation at any particular point. To illustrate sampling point p1 and p2 should yield the following results:

p1: {0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.0}

(so equal parts of biome 1, 2 and 3
respectively, and no contribution from biome 4).

p2: {0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0}

(equal parts of biome 1 and 3 and nothing from the other).

My gut tells me it might be possible somehow using the hue value of each biome, but I might be wrong. Ideally I would like to encode as many biomes as there are hue values, but as long as I can fit at least 32 I would be happy. What do you think, is it possible, and if so, how?

[image: Example of biomes represented in an image]

Comment: I don't understand what is the relationship between biomes and hues.  I don't know what it means to "generate biomes".  Can you state your problem in a self-contained way that doesn't require us to know anything about biomes or about the approach you are currently taking?

Comment: @D.W. So the world has a map, and the map is divided into different biomes represented in this image above, we can think of a biome as just an integer if thats easier. To generate biomes means just to segment the image like I've done in the example above. If we disregard the hue, all we would need to do would just be to have a map of hues and look up the hue of a certain pixel to find out which biome we are in, but the problem I'm trying to solve is how to handle the blurred edge _between_ biomes. Does this help you understand the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the blurred edges in the figure. How are these regions defined? Some fixed distance from the exact edges between the regions? One option would be to compute these regions, assign all of them an arbitrary unused color, and store the relation of this colour in the look-up table. Would this be sufficient? Or do you want to assign colours in such a way that the biome colours can be derived purely from the edge colour?